# Laravel getting data from two tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **users** table:

- ID
- username
- user_status <- which can be 0 or 1, depending if the user is active or not.

I also have a table **user_status**:

- user_status_id
- user_status_description

How can I get data from user_status_description in an elegant way?
I can get the user_status with `{{Auth::user()->user_status}}` or via UsersController (`$user_status = auth()->user()->user_status;`), but I can get a hold on how to join with another table, so I could do something like `Auth::user()->user_status_description` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by `Belongsto` relationship.
Put below relation in User eloquent

```
public function statusDescription() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\UserStatus', 'user_status', 'user_status_id');
}
```

To get user `user_status_description` as bellows.

```
Auth::user()->statusDescription->user_status_description;
```

Comment: With this, I get an error that Base table or view not found - and it is looking for user_status**es** table. Do I need to add something to the UserStatus model?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `UserStatus` model

Comment: I did it, but what should I put in it?

Comment: Just put fillable properties.
`protected $fillable = ['user_status_id', 'user_status_description']`

Comment: The same error - it still looks for user_statuses table which is not existent, I do have a user_status table. I don't see that anywhere is defined to look for user_statuses

Comment: You table must name `user_statuses`. if not you can use table properties.
` protected $table = 'your_table_name';`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit intimidating.

1. Create a migration file so that you can add a column to users table.
2. In the migration file create a column named 'user_status_description'
3. Copy all the data from user_status table user_status_description to users

table user_status_description column.By using user_id.

4.Drop the user status table.

Then you can easily  do Auth::user()->user_status_description

Comment: I could do that, but I want to keep that separate. Mainly because to get a grip on this, because I also plan to use more tables as well for other stuff (user meta data, the app will have some reports etc., - I should be able to easily connect two tables)